# How can I get the value of a select option with express.js?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I would like to retrieve the "value" parameter with the post method using express.js. I can easily retrieve the value that was entered in an input, but I cannot come up with options from a selection. Here is what I tried.

myFile.js:

```js
app.post("/dashboard/:guildID", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
        var storedSettings = await GuildSettings.findOne({ gid: guild.id });
        if (!storedSettings) {
          const newSettings = new GuildSettings({
            gid: guild.id
          });
          await newSettings.save().catch(()=>{});
          storedSettings = await GuildSettings.findOne({ gid: guild.id });
        }
        storedSettings.prefix = req.body.prefix
        storedSettings.channel_test = req.body.channel_name

        await storedSettings.save().catch(() => {});

    });
```

myEJS.ejs file (html):

```html
  <div>
    <form method="POST">
    <select>
      <% 
      let channelsText = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'text');
      channelsText.forEach(channel => { %>

      <option name="channel_name" value="<%= channel.id %>">#<%= channel.name %></option>
      
      <% }) %>

    </select>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I removed unnecessary code.

`console.log(req.body.channel_name)` = `undefined`.

I recall that `req.body.prefix` (which comes from an input tag) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `name` attribute to `select` element:

```
<select name="channel_name">
    <%
    let channelsText = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == 'text');
    channelsText.forEach(channel => { %>

    <option name="channel_name" value="<%= channel.id %>">#<%= channel.name %></option>

    <% }) %>

</select>
```